# Multi-year time series charge with shaded range in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have these charts that I've created in Excel from dataframes of a structure like such:

[image]

so that the chart can be created like this, stacking the `5-Year Range` area on top of the `Min` range (no fill) so that the range area can be shaded. The min/max/range/avg columns all calculate off of 2016-2020.

[image: 5-Year Range Chart]

I know that I can plot lines for multiple years on the same axis by using a date index and applying month labels, but is there a way to replicate the shading of this chart, more specifically if my dataframes are in a simple date index-value format, like so:

```
            Quantity
1/1/2016    6
2/1/2016    4
3/1/2016    1
4/1/2016    10
5/1/2016    7
6/1/2016    10
7/1/2016    10
8/1/2016    2
9/1/2016    1
10/1/2016   2
11/1/2016   3
…   …
1/1/2020    4
2/1/2020    8
3/1/2020    3
4/1/2020    5
5/1/2020    8
6/1/2020    6
7/1/2020    6
8/1/2020    7
9/1/2020    8
10/1/2020   5
11/1/2020   4
12/1/2020   3
1/1/2021    9
2/1/2021    7
3/1/2021    7
```

I haven't been able to find anything similar in the plot libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two step process

1. restructure DF so that years are columns, rows indexed by uniform date time
2. plot using **matplotlib**

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# straight date as index, quantity as column
d = pd.date_range("1-Jan-2016", "1-Mar-2021", freq="MS")
df = pd.DataFrame({"Quantity":np.random.randint(1, 10, len(d))}, index=d)


# re-structure as multi-index, make year column
# add calculated columns
dfg = (df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.map(lambda d: dt.date(dt.date.today().year, d.month, d.day)), 
                                               df.index.year], names=["month","year"]))
 .unstack("year")
 .droplevel(0, axis=1)
 .assign(min=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if dfa[c].count()==12]].min(axis=1),
         max=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if dfa[c].count()==12]].max(axis=1),
         avg=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if dfa[c].count()==12]].mean(axis=1).round(1),
        )
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[14,4])

# now plot all the parts
ax.fill_between(dfg.index, dfg["min"], dfg["max"], label="5y range", facecolor="oldlace")
ax.plot(dfg.index, dfg[2020], label="2020", c="r")
ax.plot(dfg.index, dfg[2021], label="2021", c="g")
ax.plot(dfg.index, dfg.avg, label="5 yr avg", c="y", ls=(0,(1,2)), lw=3)

# adjust axis
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
ax.legend(loc = 'best')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry Rob, totally missed this!
This worked, I have one last question - if I have weekly data across multiple years, how do I cope with that? I can convert the year-week format to datetime (eg. 2018-W04) but then I will get different dates based on the years. Is there any way to keep it as the week number and graph the multiple years?

Comment: it you change way multi-index is built,  you can do weekly `dfg = (df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.isocalendar().week, df.index.isocalendar().year], names=["week","year"]))
 .loc[lambda dfa: dfa.index.get_level_values("week")<53]
` just need to consider frequency of input data to avoid duplicates.  I changed to "W" ok, "D" not ok

Comment: So when I try and plot that it returns ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: `dfg = (df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.isocalendar().week.astype(int), df.index.isocalendar().year], names=["week","year"]))
 .loc[lambda dfa: dfa.index.get_level_values("week")<53]
 .unstack("year")
 .droplevel(0, axis=1)
 .assign(min=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if dfa[c].count()==52]].min(axis=1),
         max=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if dfa[c].count()==52]].max(axis=1),
         avg=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,[c for c in dfa.columns if dfa[c].count()==52]].mean(axis=1).round(1),
        )
)
` the `astype()` is needed ...

Comment: Thank you! I actually figured that part out, I'm just having a difficult time translating it to the plotting since the MonthLocator isn't applicable here

Comment: Correct - when the axis becomes a week number it's no longer a date so MonthLocator is not required